# Bash command line arg to pick which array of strings to for loop through

Tags: bash

The bash script will contain inside it multiple arrays, each with different cities, and the command line arg $1 is how to pick which array to loop through, so statically to do GA its this

```
#!/bin/bash
GA=( Atlanta Rome )
FL=( Jacksonville Miami )

for city in "${GA[@]}"
do
  echo $city
done
```

But how to use command line arg $1 to pick which array to go through?  I know that brace expansion cannot do variables, so I guess need to do this without the braces, but not sure how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `nameref` variable (see the example in the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html)):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -n arr=$1
GA=( Atlanta Rome )
FL=( Jacksonville Miami )

for city in "${arr[@]}"; do
  echo "$city"
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.sh GA
Atlanta
Rome
$ ./script.sh FL
Jacksonville
Miami
```